# How to INSERT SQL statements INTO table

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, how do I insert a row which has one column that takes an SQL statement (SELECT) as value? In other words, how to I tell the SQL interpreter not to try to parse that statement and give me errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in quotes like any other character.

```
INSERT INTO myTable
('MySQLColumn')
VALUES
('SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable')
```

Comment: How do you run sql on a ms-access db? I'm using 2010. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway without using vba?

Comment: @Ash: You can just use a `query`.

Comment: Theoretically, if you loaded the table in a form, you could create a command button that would run a macro that might be able to execute the SQL statement of the current record. But maybe not. I don't use macros, so can't really say. It's far, far easier with VBA if you're storing your SQL strings in a table like this. I've never found a need for such a thing in my 16 years of professional Access development.